# Error when retrieving location metrics

Tags: python, json, post, request, google-my-business-api

I'm trying to retrieve location metrics in my app.
The way I do it is described [here.](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/insight-data)
in the google oauth playground its work fine, but when i do it in my app i'm getting error in my response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400, 
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest", 
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"basicRequest\": Cannot bind query parameter. 'basicRequest' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types."
          }, 
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"encodingType\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'encodingType' could not be found in request message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ], 
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"basicRequest\": Cannot bind query parameter. 'basicRequest' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"encodingType\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'encodingType' could not be found in request message.", 
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

My post requst:

```
data = json.load(open('request.json'))
url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts/1054012049xxxxxxxxxx/locations:reportInsights'
        e = google.post(url=url, data=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', "Content-Length": 291})
```

and the json file with  request body:

```
{
  "locationNames": "accounts/105401204xxxxxxxx/locations/616918704xxxxxxxxxx",
  "basicRequest": {
     "metricRequests": {
               "metric": "ALL"
     },
    "timeRange": {
      "startTime": "2017-09-02T01:01:01.045123456Z",
      "endTime": "2017-10-02T23:59:59.045123456Z"
    }
  }
}
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your payload is "metricRequests" key is an array of metric requests but in your case, you are passing it as an object. modify it and resubmit